# I am getting an error in my npm when trying to install expo-cli globally

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I try to install `npm` globally, using the command

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

I am getting an error that says

> npm install -g expo-cli
> npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED
> npm ERR! error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-20T21_10_42_635Z-debug-0.log

Although I just updated my node version to version *17.9.0* and my `npm` version is *8.5.5*.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: use the  latest LTS version of node (currently `16.14.2 `)

Comment: I have insatalled that just now, but its still giving the same error

Comment: What is in the debug log mentioned in the error?